# why the fancybox is not appearing here?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

All I want is this :

```
$('#divEditable2').fancybox();
```

I of course tried that, but when it didn't work, I even tried this. Still no output.

Here's my full code :

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="fbTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="InlineEditing.fbTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Scripts/fancybox/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"
        media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {

                alert('loading...');
                var divObject = document.createElement('div');
                divObject.setAttribute('id', 'divEditable2');
                var editorContent = '<textarea rows="5" cols="55">sample text' + '</textarea><input type="button" value="Save Edits" id="btnSaveEdits" style="margin-left: 300px;" onclick="HideTextArea(event);"/><input type="button" value="Cancel Edits" id="btnCancelEdits" style="margin-left: 5px;" onclick="DoCleanUp();"/>';

                $('#divEditable2').fancybox({
                    'modal' : true,
                    'type' : 'inline',
                    'autoDimensions': false,
                    'width': '700',
                    'height': '320',
                    'showCloseButton': false,
                    'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                    'enableEscapeButton': false,
                    'content': editorContent
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="divEditable2">
            This is the test div.</div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="show" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

On click of the button, there is no error(firebug), but still I don't understand why the fancybox does not appear??? All I want is, to show a div inside a fancybox. There must be something really-really stupid I'm missing out on, but just could not figure it out myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are misunderstanding the logic of fancybox. What this line does

```
$('#divEditable2').fancybox();
```

... is to bind fancybox to the selector with `id="divEditable2"`. You would actually need to click on that selector in order to fire fancybox ...of course you can't, first because is hidden and second because is not a link, is a `DIV`

What you can try is to append the value of the variable `editorContent` to the selector `'#divEditable2'` and then target the second as `href`, something like:

```
$('#divEditable2').append('<textarea rows="5" cols="55">sample text' + '</textarea><input type="button" value="Save Edits" id="btnSaveEdits" style="margin-left: 300px;" onclick="HideTextArea(event);"/><input type="button" value="Cancel Edits" id="btnCancelEdits" style="margin-left: 5px;" onclick="DoCleanUp();"/>');
```

then replace this line of your code:

```
$('#divEditable2').fancybox({
```

by this:

```
$.fancybox({
```

and replace this line:

```
'content': editorContent
```

by this:

```
'href': '#divEditable2'
```

Additionally, in order to clean up your code, don't use integer values with quotes so these

```
'width': '700',
'height': '320',
```

should be

```
'width': 700,
'height': 320,
```

Comment: Thanks man...I knew I was missing something really stupid. Your very first line showed the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing some thing like .

Keep the div in the markup don't generate it dynamically.

Append the text area thing to div and then give a call to your fancy box.